# laravel getRealPath() function

Tags: laravel, email

i have an email send using ajax laravel, in controller file

```
    public function SendEmailByLaravel(Request $request)
    {
        $data = [
            'subject' => $request->get('subject'),
            'email'   => $request->get('email'),
            'body'    => $request->get('body'),
            'image'   => $request->get('image')
        ];
        //dd($subject . " " . $email . " " . $body . " " . $image);

        //dd($data['subject']);

        Mail::to($data['email'])->send(new PersonalMail($data));
    }
```

and in mail file:

```
    public function build()
    {
        $body = $this->data['body'];
        $subject = $this->data['subject'];

        if ($this->data['image'] != null) {
            return $this->subject($this->data['subject'])
                ->view('Emails.PersonalMail', compact('subject', 'body'))
                ->attach($this->data['image']->getRealPath(), [
                    'as' => $this->data['image']->getClientOriginalName()
                ]);
        } else {
            return $this->subject($this->data['subject'])
                ->view('Emails.PersonalMail', compact('subject', 'body'));
        }
    }
```

i get an error {message: Call to a member function getRealPath() on string", exception: "Error",}

Comment: `enctype='multipart/form-data'`

Comment: am using ajax and i put enctype='multipart/form-data'

Comment: The file is not in `$request->get('image')` but in `$request->file('image')`

Comment: $request->file('image') working and an email was send, but the attachment not recieved